# How can I POST data to a WebAPI controller from Angular's $http service?

Tags: c#, javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621706/posting-from-angular-to-net-webapi).

Here is my C# code:

```
public class MyModel
{
    int? ID { get; set; }
}

public class MyResourceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public MyModel MyPostAction(MyModel model)
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var data = { model: { ID: 1 } };
$http.post(
    '/api/MyResource/MyPostAction',
    JSON.stringify(data),
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
);
```

When I set a breakpoint in my action and `model.ID` is `null` instead of `1`.  How can I POST a complex object?

Comment: You can skip the stringify by using [FromBody] in the header.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869763/how-to-post-an-object-to-webapi-using-angularjs/27869884#27869884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `public` to the property on `MyModel` fixed it (*facepalm*).

I ended up using this on the client:

```
var data = { ID: 1 };
$http.post('/api/MyResource/MyPostAction', data);
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to wrap your data into `model` property:

```
var data = { ID: 1 };
$http.post('/api/MyResource/MyPostAction', data);
```

Comment: I was missing `public` on my property... This helped though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$http.post('/api/MyResource/MyPostAction', data);
```

Remove the JSON.stringify and post the data as is.

You don't need to specify json header either as it is the default for post.

On the server:

Remove Xml from webapi if you're only using json

```
//WebApiConfig.js
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

Comment: That didn't work. :/ (I took out the header config object and I took out the JSON.stringify)

Comment: Oh I've used the Package Manager to get Ninject and Newtonsoft's JSON.NET.  Maybe that's interfering somehow?

Comment: JSON is only the default if data is supplied and not undefined. Otherwise it is XML. This is important if you don't have a media formatter for XML for your Web API controller.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Strange. Have updated the answer to remove the xml formatter from the webapi, although it shouldn't be that stupid to try xml when the http header states json

Comment: I was missing `public` on my property.  Thanks for all the help though.