# How to post an object to WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out how to post an object from my form to a web api service. Within my controller I defined a model that I wanted to add input values to.

```
$scope.Label;
```

within my input fields I have them bound using `ng-model` such as:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="label.isPublic" />
<input type="text" ng-model="label.labelName" required focus-me />
```

On the submission of the form these two fields a passed to my service and submitted to my WebApi

I have tried this submission in two ways:

```
function addLabel(label) {
        var mylabel = encodeURIComponent(angular.toJson(label));
        return $http.post('reportLibrary/createlabel/', { params: label }, {

        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

and also as the following without declaring parameters

```
function addLabel(label) {
        var mylabel = encodeURIComponent(angular.toJson(label));
        return $http.post('reportLibrary/createlabel/', label , {

        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

In the webAPI I have a method setup for the post

```
 [Route ("reportLibrary/createlabel/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public DTOs.ReportLabel CreateLabel(DTOs.ReportLabel json)
        {
            DTOs.ReportLabel result = new DTOs.ReportLabel();

        //.... do stuff
            return result;
        }
```

The ReportLabel (dto) is defined as follows:

```
public class ReportLabel
{
    public Int64 LabelId { get; set; }
    public string LabelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }//placeholder?

}
```

The issue I have is when I post an object from my angular service it shows up as null within the API. If I change the type in the method to something like a JToken or JObject the values appear.

Can anyone help me understand why when I define the type that it is not passed across from angular?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may be doing an extra step. You don't need to encode in json then pass in in json

```
return $http.post('reportLibrary/createlabel/', { LabelId: 101, LabelName: 'myname' }, {
```

then

```
 public DTOs.ReportLabel CreateLabel([FromBody]ReportLabel reportLabel)
```

Take a look at the network values going by and you should see in debug tools or fiddler the actual posted values (form values).

Comment: this did in fact work but this seems a bit heavy handed. What if I had an object that had 10 or 20 properties on it? It seems as if there should be a way to just pass the object vs declaring and setting each property/field. I'd be interested to see other options

Comment: My concern is not so much that it's heavy handed but feels like magic.  Microsoft tries to make it easy by looking for how you pass data and then trying to map to it.  I've never had much success with passing parameters but I do know it's possible.  When I want full control I use the forms collection (I posted it here:  http://peterkellner.net/2013/08/18/collection-form-post-parameters-in-webapi-controller/ )