# Passing params from AngularJS to C# Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs

I've tried researching this but I can't find anything anywhere that's helpful or any relevant answers.

For my angular controller I have:

```
app.controller('AdminCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.data = {
    Name: '',
    Password: ''
},
$scope.login = function (data) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/login/postlogin',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            data: $scope.data
        }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert('success!');
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    })
}
});
```

For my c# controller I have a very basic setup:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PostLogin(string data) {          
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

My issue is that inside of the c# controller, data is always null. Does anyone know how to pass the name and password params over to the c# controller? I know for a fact that I am recieving values for them from my textboxes that I have. I am also recieving the success message/alert.Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post an object to WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869763/how-to-post-an-object-to-webapi). and there are many more answers here on SO. use the search function.

Comment: seems like you are reading jQuery ajax docs to use `$http` and not reading angular docs

Comment: For the one who voted to close as "too broad", it's not.

Comment: @Nasreddine I took a look at that document before I posted here but it didn't really help me with what I am trying to do. After taking a look at the posted answers along with the other question I am getting closer to what I am trying to accomplish though.

Comment: `$scope.data` isn't a `string`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, actually, if you take a look at HaukurHaf's post, you can pass them in as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is not a string. In c# make an object with Name and Password as properties and have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostLogin(Data data) {
```

Edit in response to comment:
Yes you need to include the namespace that Data is in in your controller. You could try putting the Data object directly above.

```
 public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

For clarity, data should not be stringified, instead just sent as `data: data`

Comment: I am trying to use the (Data data) but it keeps telling me that Data could not be found. Is there a namespace that I'm missing? I have successfully gotten it to work with the solution HaudurHaf posted, but I am wanting to pass it as an object since there could potentially be several params that I could be passing in here. When I use the generic (Object data) nothing comes through.

Comment: Glad you have it working, but yes good idea to pass objects. Hopefully that edit helps. You won't want to stringify it - will edit answer to make this clear in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That worked perfectly. I appreciate the help! If I could I'd give you a +1.

Comment: Thanks. I have already voted your question up; someone was mean and had downvoted it before me.

Answer (score 1):

Just send $scope.data directly, dont stringify it.  Then modify your PostLogin method so it accepts two strings, one called Name and one called Password.