# POST data from AngularJS client to ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm a little confused as to how AngularJS is POSTing data to my WebAPI controller. Normally, when I would POST data from AngularJS to an MVC controller, I would do something like this:

```
var data = { "value": "some string" };
$http.post('/api/products', { data
}).success(function () {...
```

However, in the WebAPI controller, the string value is always coming back as null.

Do I need to post the data a little differently when passing data to a web api controller?

Here is the method in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
     .....
    }
```

**edit**
Not sure if this helps, but this is the header from Fiddler:

> POST http://localhost:58167/api/products/ HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   localhost:58167 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 11 Accept:
>   application/json, text/plain, */* Origin: http://localhost:58167
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36 Content-Type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8 Referer: http://localhost:58167/
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> some string

Comment: see this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621706/posting-from-angular-to-net-webapi

Comment: @Prashant Yea, I read that post already...including a few others. It appears that I'm doing everything correctly but the value always shows as null. If I'm using [FormBody] then I don't need to use Stringify, correct? I

Comment: did you give content type as JSON in your header

Comment: @Prashant Yes -- I tried that too.

Comment: `var data = "some string" ;`

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe - still null

Comment: Perhaps change your Web API from accepting a string to accepting a model object, such as `public class Product { public string Value {get; set;} }`

Comment: @mason Wow -- that works! So is it a best practice to pass objects rather than a string?

Comment: I don't know about "best practice", as that's really subjective. If it works, then do it. And besides - how often are you posting *just* a string? You'll usually be posting a complex type anyways.

Comment: @mason Very good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Web API to accept a complex type (model) instead of a string.

```
public class Product
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Product product)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(product.Value);
}
```