# passing complex object to web api from angular js it always return 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

My javascript method-

```
visitorApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.submit = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            var loginModel = {
                UserName: $scope.UserName,
                PassWord: $scope.Password
            };           

        $http.post(
            '/api/VisitorWeb/VerfiyLogin',
            JSON.stringify(loginModel),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).success(function (data) {
            alert("Hi" +data);
            $scope.message = data;
        });


    }
}
```

});

My web api method -

```
[HttpPost]
        public UserLoginDomainModel VerifyLogin(UserLoginDomainModel loginModel)
        {
            //do some business logic
            return loginModel;
        }
```

My webapiconfig file

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
        }
    }
```

I am getting 404 response from server.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:43516/api/VisitorWeb/VerfiyLogin"
```

I was try to follow this link
[POSTing from Angular to .net WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621706/posting-from-angular-to-net-webapi)
but some how it is not working for me.

Comment: Is it cross origin ?

Comment: a stupid question but your front end and backend are running on the same instance and port ?shouldn't it be like this $http.post(apiHost+ '/api/VisitorWeb/VerfiyLogin' ..

Comment: @YinGang- it is not cross origin. Everything is in the same web project

Comment: @MayK- it is running on same port.

Comment: @MayK- is it compulsory to provide the localhost port in uri, without it will never work?

Comment: you have to add context before url  as /context/api/VisitorWeb/VerfiyLogin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo here:

```
 $http.post(
            '/api/VisitorWeb/VerfiyLogin',
            JSON.stringify(loginModel),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
```

Your service method is named VerifyLogin and not VerfiyLogin from what I can see.

Comment: you got me , it was the typo which was the problem, now it is working.